# Update mysql data via json

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey all So I am able to update the records from a json url and put it into Mysql now I am trying to update the records and it only grabs 1 value and updates all the records to the new value so its updating the existing records with only 1 record here is what I am using

```
$ApiLink     = "JSON URL HERE";
$json_decode = (json_decode(file_get_contents($ApiLink), true));
$output      = $json_decode["character_list"];

/************************************************/

$do_stuff = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE damage_given_vehicle SET veh_id=:veh_id, veh_name=:veh_name, veh_total=:total_value, veh_faction_nc=:veh_faction_nc, veh_faction_tr=:veh_faction_tr, veh_faction_vs=:veh_faction_vs WHERE character_number = :char_id");

foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    $character_id[$key] = $output[$key]["id"];

    if (isset($output[$key]["stats"]["vehicle_kills"]["vehicle"])) {
        $vehicle_kills[$key] = $output[$key]["stats"]["vehicle_kills"]["vehicle"];
        foreach ($vehicle_kills[$key] as $row) {
            $do_stuff->bindValue(':char_id', $update_id);
            $do_stuff->bindValue(':veh_id', $row["id"]);
            $do_stuff->bindValue(':veh_name', $row["name"]);
            $do_stuff->bindValue(':total_value', $row["value"]);
            $do_stuff->bindValue(':veh_faction_nc', $row["faction"]["nc"]);
            $do_stuff->bindValue(':veh_faction_tr', $row["faction"]["tr"]);
            $do_stuff->bindValue(':veh_faction_vs', $row["faction"]["vs"]);
            $do_stuff->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

the database looks like this at first:

```
key | id | name | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 |
5428029729515051201     11  name_1 6 45 23 34 
5428029729515051201     11  name_2 2 34     63 63
5428029729515051201     11  name_3 34 0     17  17
```

after I use the update script it turns those values into:

```
5428029729515051201     11  name    34  0   17  17
5428029729515051201     11  name    34  0   17  17
5428029729515051201     11  name    34  0   17  17
```

if you are curious how the script enters the json data here you go:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    INSERT INTO damage_given_vehicle (
        character_number, veh_id, veh_name, veh_total,
        veh_faction_nc, veh_faction_tr, veh_faction_vs)
    VALUES(
        :char_id, :veh_id, :veh_name, :total_value,
        :veh_faction_nc, :veh_faction_tr, :veh_faction_vs)
");
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    $character_id[$key] = $output[$key]["id"];

    if (isset($output[$key]["stats"]["vehicle_kills"]["vehicle"])) {
        $vehicle_kills[$key] = $output[$key]["stats"]["vehicle_kills"]["vehicle"];
        foreach ($vehicle_kills[$key] as $row) {
            $stmt->bindValue(':char_id', $character_id[$key]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':veh_id', $row["id"]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':veh_name', $row["name"]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':total_value', $row["value"]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':veh_faction_nc', $row["faction"]["nc"]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':veh_faction_tr', $row["faction"]["tr"]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':veh_faction_vs', $row["faction"]["vs"]);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get it to update every array seperately, If I do a var_dump on any of the $row[""] they produce the array how it should be displayed but when it goes through and enters into mysql it only grabs 1 value

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set `$update_id` and whats values has `character_number` in your table? For me it just looks like you are overwriting every entry of your table within every loop because you always have the same `$update_id` which is in your `where` statement. So in the end you get the values of the last loop for every entry in your table.

But its hard to find out because you haven't posted the real tables.

Comment: do you want me to post the actual mysql table ? the $update_ID is the primary key that is common for each row

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you set `$update_id` because it's not set in the code you posted at the top. Its crucial that you match exactly the row you want to update in your `WHERE` clause. Otherwise the wrong or even all rows are being updated in every loop.

Comment: This is the top portion of where $update_id is coming from 


$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT character_number FROM characters");
 # setting the fetch mode
 $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 while ($update_stats = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $update_id = $update_stats["character_number"];

Comment: What values do you have in the column `character_number` just a few examples.

Comment: ID | CHARACTER NUMBER | FACTION | RANK | NAME


1 5428029729515051201 nc 42 FrenchBread

Comment: Yeah there is your problem as I stated before. The character_number is always the same. As I can see when I compare it to the rows in your question. Thats why you only get the last data of the loop in every of your rows. The `$update_id` has to be specific for the desired row. Or you have to change the `WHERE` clause to another column. Can't help you more.

Comment: is there a way to go through each table where $update_id is present ?

Comment: if I removed the WHERE character_number = :char_id it still doesnt update the table with the array  :|

Comment: This is the array that I am using and is repeated 6 more times with each having different values

array (size=4)
  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'lightning' (length=9)
  'value' => string '231185' (length=6)
  'faction' => 
    array (size=3)
      'tr' => string '156759' (length=6)
      'nc' => string '0' (length=1)
      'vs' => string '74426' (length=5)